# Timeshift GUI not showing snapshots

Tags: gui, rsync, snapshot, timeshift

I use Ubuntu 22.04.

I've been trying to create snapshots on my internal disk. Even though the snapshots are created, they are not shown in the GUI.

I've tried formatting the disk and reinstalling Timeshift.

Timeshift GUI:

[image: This is the timeshift GUI]

This is the snapshot I created manually. It contains the 4 files of the snapshot.

[image: This is the snapshot i created manually. It contains the 4 files of the snapshot]

The snapshots can't be found through the console with `sudo timeshift --list` either.

[image: The snapshots can't be found through the console as well]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Use the ppa repository to install timeshift.

Do

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/timeshift -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install timeshift
```

This ensures that you have the latest stable version. Without this the info.json file is not generated, and the snapshot seems to be incomplete. Also, the snapshot won't show on the GUI nor the CLI.

Comment: The linked PPA is in fact for the latest development builds of Timeshift, and should not be considered to be stable in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it's this solution worked fine for me, but if you want you can just reorder `filters`ins settings like these screenshots.

Filters Section:

[image: Filters Section]

and

Snapshot find:

[image: Snapshot find]